# How to use automatic hyphens in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Is there any way to get automatic hyphenating in Google Chrome? I've read a lot of threads about this but no one gives a real anwser to this question. My problem is that i get the text dynamically from the backend of the CMS so i can't add things like `&shy;`.

Would be nice if anybody knows how to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenator can help with that on the client side; I think a server-side implementation in PHP is available somewhere as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of version Chrome 71, auto-hyphenation is still only available on Android and Mac -- not on Windows and Linux. You can track the [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652964) for updates. Also see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens).